# Batch: Replacing just the first character in a string if it is a certain character

Tags: string, batch-file, substring

I have several datalines like so:

```
v1.4.00.29                                                           
- SP.CNG v1.0.2.2                                                           
Update Kit - Secure USB Token v1.1.1.1                                                           
- HI_3997 v1.0.3997.1                                                           
- HI_4009 v1.0.4009.1                                                           
- HI_3585 v1.0.3585                                                           
Update Kit - RM4 v1.0.1202.4                                                           
Update Kit - DN Series v1.0.4.1
```

Is there some easy way to check if the first character is a `-` and then delete this PLUS the space next to them so that the line is aligned to the other lines.

My first try was just to delete the `-`and `spaces`resulting in a not looking result as ALL `-` are replaced:

```
set tmp=!tmp:-=!
set tmp=!tmp: =!
```

Comment: why not simply remove "dash+space" (`set tmp=!tmp:- =!`) instead of removing every dash and every space?

Comment: He then also removes i there is a DASh and SPACE at different positions

Comment: ...which may or may not be a good idea. If not, TripeHound's solution is the best to remove them only at the beginning. (I just wondered why you removed both chars independently instead of their combination)

Comment: To align with other lines, I would suggest it may be better to prepend eleven spaces to any lines beginning with `-`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the "substring" method of referring to environment variables. In brief:

```
%TMP:~n,m%
```

will extract `m` characters from `TMP`, starting with the `n`<sup>th</sup>, where counting starts from zero. (You can also omit `,m` to get "*the rest of the string*" and use negative numbers to mean "*from the end of the string*" –  see the output of `SET /?` for more details).

In your case, something like the following should work:

```
if "%TMP:~0,2%" == "- "     set "TMP=%TMP:~2%"
```

This checks whether the first two characters are a minus and a space (you could relax this to just checking the first character if needed). If there's a match, it replaces `TMP` with all characters starting with the third (`0`=1<sup>st</sup>, `1`=2<sup>nd</sup> etc.).

Comment: @SRel While they can sometimes be fiddly, the substring commands can be quite powerful. For instance, with `SET Y=4` and `SET STR=abcdefgh`, then `echo !STR:~%Y%,1!` will extract the 5th letter (`e`). (Providing `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is in effect).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the following code that uses [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) (the string to process is stored in variale `tmp`):

```cmd
if "- !tmp:*- !"=="!tmp!" set "tmp=!tmp:*- =!"
```

This removes everything up to and including the first occurrence of `-` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> from the string and precedes the result with `-` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>; if this is now equal to the original string then the first `-` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> must be at the beginning, so remove it; otherwise do not alter the string.